# old iPod touch 1.1.4 youtube app hasn't worked since Sept 2011 or so

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I've been happy with my jailbroken iPod touch and didn't want to upgrade beyond 1.1.4. However, since late last year, perhaps September, the YouTube application hasn't worked, giving the uninformative error "Cannot connect to YouTube". Likewise I cannot reach Google using SSL, only straight HTTP. The error with https://google.com/ first successfully redirects to https://www.google.com/m, but then gives this error:

> "Error 502 (Server Error)!!1"

(sic) with the colored Google logo and

> "502. That's an error. The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds. That's all we know".

But it is not temporary, and I believe the two problems are related. I've edited the Cookies.plist file and cut out the google.com and youtube.com cookies, no help. I'm wondering if it has something to do with root certs, but don't know the plist for those. Any ideas?

Comment: Your old software is old. I think it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Maybe your question would have more luck on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Coyote I think SuperUser would send it straight back to us. It belongs here, horrifically outdated software or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I suspect your problem started when the YouTube API 1.0 was dropped by google.

Google [notified](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v1_deprecation_notice) developers that the YouTube API was deprecated in 2008. Since they keep deprecated APIs running for 3 years, 2011 would be the time they turned the switch on it. **It would make sense if all apps and webpages relying on the YouTube API v1.0 failed when they shut it down**. They had a lot of problems with YouTube in september 2011 (example [with 502 errors](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/archive/GJcQrXvtabg)). So it's reasonable to say that your iPod will never be able to connect to YouTube if you keep using the early 2008 iPhone OS 1.1.4.

Google released the YouTube Data API (v2.0) around march 2008, after the iOS 1.1.4 was released.

I fear the only solution to get your 1.1.4 device to play YouTube properly would be to get Google to turn the old API back on... Or simply update your iPod :(

Comment: thanks, but I'm much more interested in being able to use Google securely than accessing youtube. apologies that I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: update: the SSL access to google.com was restored a few days ago, though YouTube still fails.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I fear the API has definitively changed regardless of the SSL access.